# Convert a column of timestamps into periods in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, datetime-format

I have a column of timestamps that need to be converted into period ('Month'). e.g.

```
1985-12-31 00:00:00 to 1985-12
```

Pandas has a `.to_period()` function, but:

- [`pd.DatetimeIndex.to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html?highlight=datetimeindex) only works on a timestamp index, not column. So you can only have a period index, but not a period column?
- and that function only work if timestamps are the only index, i.e. not if timestamps are part of a multIndex.

Anyway how do I use this on an arbitary Pandas column, not just a tiemstamp index or period index?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I came across this thread today, and after further digging found that Pandas .15 affords an easier option use .dt, you can avoid the step of creating an index and create the column directly. You can use the following to get the same result:

```
df[1] = df[0].dt.to_period('M')
```

Comment: This does not work: 'DatetimeProperties' object has no attribute 'to_priod'

Comment: @AliKhosro change "to_priod" to "to_period"

Answer (score 10):

You're right, you need to do this one DatetimeIndex objects rather than just columns of datetimes. However, this is pretty easy - just wrap it in a DatetimeIndex constructor:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2014-01-01', freq='2w', periods=12))

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
            0
0  2014-01-05
1  2014-01-19
2  2014-02-02
3  2014-02-16
4  2014-03-02
5  2014-03-16
6  2014-03-30
7  2014-04-13
8  2014-04-27
9  2014-05-11
10 2014-05-25
11 2014-06-08

In [13]: pd.DatetimeIndex(df[0]).to_period('M')
Out[13]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.period.PeriodIndex'>
freq: M
[2014-01, ..., 2014-06]
length: 12
```

*This is a PeriodIndex, but you can make it a column:*

```
In [14]: df[1] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df[0]).to_period('M')

In [15]: df
Out[15]:
            0        1
0  2014-01-05  2014-01
1  2014-01-19  2014-01
2  2014-02-02  2014-02
3  2014-02-16  2014-02
4  2014-03-02  2014-03
5  2014-03-16  2014-03
6  2014-03-30  2014-03
7  2014-04-13  2014-04
8  2014-04-27  2014-04
9  2014-05-11  2014-05
10 2014-05-25  2014-05
11 2014-06-08  2014-06
```

*You can do a similar trick if the timestamps are part of a MultiIndex by extracting that "column" <strike>and passing it to DatetimeIndex as above</strike>, e.g. using [`df.index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#reconstructing-the-level-labels):*
For example:

```
df[2] = 2
df.set_index([0, 1], inplace=True)
df.index.get_level_values(0)  # returns a DatetimeIndex
```

Comment: Could you please give an example of extracting level=1 index from multiIndex as a column?

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#reconstructing-the-level-labels i.e. `df.index.get_level_values(1)`, it seems that this returns a DatetimeIndex if this is dates.

Comment: iirc this should work in master / 0.14.0 and stay a periodindex

Comment: Thank you @AndyHayden. Is it possible to change a timestamps index within a MultIndex into period index directly?

Comment: @user3576212 good question, I don't *think* so, since 0.13 (?) these are implemented with FrozenLists so more difficult to just mutate the labels :s Definitely would be good to have some more API for this kind of stuff...

Comment: Thanks. I will be great if we can have something in pandas like SAS `intck` and `intnx` functions. Because dates are not necessarily used as index all the time.

Comment: @user3576212 agree, do post an issue on github!