# Make a Year-Week column in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a column with dates. I want a column with Year-Week, for example: `2018-13`.

Here 13 represents the 13th week of the year for `04.01.2018`.

Can you help me with the code?

Input date sample:

```
0       04.01.2018
1       04.01.2018
2       04.01.2018
3       04.01.2018
4       05.01.2018
```

The post [Convert a column of timestamps into periods in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840797/convert-a-column-of-timestamps-into-periods-in-pandas) does not help with extracting year and week simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using `pandas`.

Convert your series to `datetime` and then use functionality of `datetime` objects with `pd.Series.apply` / `str.format`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['y-m'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: '{0}-{1}'.format(x.year, x.isocalendar()[1]))

#         date        y-m
# 0 2018-04-01    2018-13
# 1 2018-04-01    2018-13
# 2 2018-04-01    2018-13
# 3 2018-04-01    2018-13
# 4 2018-05-01    2018-18
```

Comment: `df.date.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')`.  But as it stands, it's not even clear if the question is asking for Pandas Periods, or string representations of them.

Comment: @jpp can I ask you one more thing? How can I make it 2018-01, not 2018-1?

Comment: You probably want to use `str(x.isocalendar()[1]).rjust(2, '0')` instead of `x.isocalendar()[1]`

Comment: @jpp, you are the best. many thanks! been googling this easy (for you, I guess) thing for 3 days :)