# Converting timestamp to date and to period

Tags: python, pandas

I know that looking at this example code, iy might seem inefficient, but on the original DF I must apply a regex function on a columns so I need to do it through iterrows.

My questions is how do I covert the date column o the data3 dataframe to a period('M') column because I want do run a groupby.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
ts = dt.datetime.now()

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'status' :  ['pending', 'pending','pending'],
    'brand' : ['brand_1', 'brand_2', 'brand_3'],
    'date' : [pd.Timestamp(dt.datetime.now()),pd.Timestamp(dt.datetime.now()),pd.Timestamp(dt.datetime.now())]})

data2 = list()
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    a = row['status']
    b = row['brand']
    c = row['date'].date()
    data2.append((a,b,c))

data3 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2,columns=['status','brand','date'])
```

```
    status    brand        date
0  pending  brand_1  2023-08-04
1  pending  brand_2  2023-08-04
2  pending  brand_3  2023-08-04
```

So, if I try to run a groupby then, I can´t get it working.

```
a = data3.groupby([data3['date'].dt.to_period('M')], observed=True).aggregate({'brand':'count'})
```

_

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[26], line 1
----> 1 a = data3.groupby([data3['date'].dt.to_period('M')], observed=True).aggregate({'brand':'count'})
      2 a

File c:\Users\fabio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:5989, in NDFrame.__getattr__(self, name)
   5982 if (
   5983     name not in self._internal_names_set
   5984     and name not in self._metadata
   5985     and name not in self._accessors
   5986     and self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name)
   5987 ):
   5988     return self[name]
-> 5989 return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

File c:\Users\fabio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\accessor.py:224, in CachedAccessor.__get__(self, obj, cls)
    221 if obj is None:
    222     # we're accessing the attribute of the class, i.e., Dataset.geo
    223     return self._accessor
--> 224 accessor_obj = self._accessor(obj)
    225 # Replace the property with the accessor object. Inspired by:
    226 # https://www.pydanny.com/cached-property.html
    227 # We need to use object.__setattr__ because we overwrite __setattr__ on
    228 # NDFrame
...
    577 elif is_period_dtype(data.dtype):
    578     return PeriodProperties(data, orig)
--> 580 raise AttributeError("Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values")

AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a column of timestamps into periods in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840797/convert-a-column-of-timestamps-into-periods-in-pandas)

Comment: If I run a simple "data3['a'] = data['date'].dt.to_period('M')", it does work, but why it does not work inside a groupby (I´ve updated my question)?

Comment: the message is quite clear: "Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values". Your column is a `date` type, not `datetime`

Comment: I got it, but datetime or datetime64[ns] are more "visually" complex information. How could I turn a date into a period? I should transform the date into a datetime into a period? Its so weird as we, humans, are more likely to transform a date into a period than a datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `.date()` in your for loop, to maintain the data type as `datetime64[ns]` like this,

```
data2 = list()
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    ...
    c = row['date'] # <-- removed `.date()`
    ...
```

Now, this works

```
data3.groupby([data3['date'].dt.to_period('M')], observed=True).aggregate({'brand':'count'})
```

---

**Output:**

```
        brand
date    
2023-08 3
```